# Get selected row id

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using below jquery to get selected row id

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          //MainContent_tbl
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#MainContent_tbl tr').click(function (event) {
                  alert(this.id); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

              });
          });



    </script>
```

My problem is that my table(MainContent_tb) is not static, i need to pass this as variable, any suggestion or remarks would be appreciated.

Comment: So, is the table *content* a variable, or the table's *id* the dynamic element?

Comment: As I understand you dynamically add/remove rows. Then when you add your row you also must associate the event handler with those new rows. I would suggest you using `jQuery.live` but will not. Don't use it. It is deprecated.

Comment: @SurrealDreams That's a good question - I assumed the ID was the dynamic part in my answer, but that may not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MainContent_tbl tr').click(function (event) {
        var elID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(elID);
    });
  });
```

This is what you are looking for!

Comment: It works like charm, thank much Jannis really appreciated your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
var tableId = 'MainContent_tbl';
$('#' + tableId + ' tr').click(function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
}
```

should work. It simply builds the selector string using the variable, rather than being hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('#'+table_id_as_variablle+' tr').click(function (event) {
       alert(this.id); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delegate` and attach `click` handler on the document with selector as `tr`. This way there will be only one click handler attached and also you don't have to bother about table id. It will work for any table. Try this.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(document).delegate('tr', 'click', function (event) {
              alert(this.id); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          
          });
      });
```

Reference: **[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)**